# CTRL-K in Vim produces unexpected results

Tags: vim

Hi I'm trying to optimise my window management in vim by mapping <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, k so i can just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to switch to the split window above the one I'm working in (I'm doing this for h,j and l also but it's only k that's causing the problem).

I've added this into my .vimrc

```
noremap <silent> <c-k> <C-W>k                                                                                                                
noremap <silent> <c-j> <C-W>j                                                                                                      
noremap <silent> <c-h> <C-W>h                                                                                                      
noremap <silent> <c-l> <C-W>l
```

However if I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, then something weird happens. It changes depending on where I am in the document.

- If I'm at the top of a document with many lines beneath my curser, the cursor hops down a few lines and columns into a completely different place.
- If I'm at the bottom of a document, it creates loads of spaces from the cursor onwards.

I've tested and removing the above lines causes the symptoms to stop happening. I'm just really confused as to what is going on!

Some info: I'm using the vim binary that comes with macvim via the command line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I've got the same issue, c-j c-h and c-l work great, but c-k doesn't.
:verbose map <C-k> says <C-k> <C-W>k

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can’t explain the second problem, but if you pasted everything directly from the vimrc then you have lots of trailing spaces that must not be there. It can explain the first problem. Try running

```
:%sm/\s\+$
```

then save and see whether problem disappears. If it is so, use

```
:set list listchars=trail:-
```

to be able to see trailing spaces so that you won’t run into this problem again.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe `<C-k>` is already mapped to something else. Try `:verbose map <C-k>`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your mapping is triggered in visual or operator mapping, where `<c-w>k` has a different meaning.

You could try this:

```
nnoremap <C-J> <C-W>j
nnoremap <C-K> <C-W>k
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W>h
nnoremap <C-L> <C-W>l
```

, which will trigger only in normal mode.

Comment: This stops the random lines appearing but the search still happens if I say press ctrl-k on the top most window. Also every time I move window focus I hear an alert bell sound.